# How to add a custom object with IBOutlet UIImageView to a UICollectionViewCell?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

Basically I want to add custom object (GameBubble) with IBOutlet UIImageView (GameBubbleImageView) into my custom collection view cells (GameBubbleCell), However I cannot link the IBOutlet imageView to the controller.

```
GameBubble:
IBOutlet UIImageView *GameBubbleImageView;

GameBubbleCell:
GameBubble *bubble;
```

In the storyboard I can only find my GameBubbleCell, so I cannot link my GameImageView to the controller.

My alternative way is to set:

```
GameBubble:
UIImage *GameBubbleImage;

GameBubbleCell:
IBOutlet UIImageView *GameBubbleImageView;
GameBubble *bubble;
```

but this is not a good MVC pattern. Is there a way to achieve my previous design?

Comment: Add full code as per .h and .m files - Code is not clear enough to answer

Comment: Without code its hard to get what you exactly are trying to do. If I understand right you're trying to add a custom class to to your view controller. This will only work if your custom class inherits from an object that can be put into a view controller (e.g. UIView, UIImageView, UITableViewCell etc).

Answer (score 0):

In storyboard drop your image view onto the collection view cell in collection view controller.
Provide some integer value to the tag field of image view in the attributes inspector.
Following code might help you:

```
-(UICollectionViewCell *) collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *identifier = @"Cell";
    UICollectionViewCell *collectionViewCell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:identifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    UIImageView *recipeImageView = (UIImageView *) [collectionViewCell viewWithTag:100];
    recipeImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[recipePhotos objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    //collectionViewCell.backgroundView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"photo-frame.png"]];
    return collectionViewCell;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Like this

```
GameBubble:
UIImageView *GameBubbleImageView;

GameBubbleCell:
IBOutlet GameBubble *bubble;
```